# Find all $x \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_{2}$ s.t. $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_{2} = \langle x \rangle \times \langle0,1\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory

> Find all $x \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_{2}$ such that $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_{2} = \langle x \rangle \times \langle0,1\rangle$.

I know the answer is: $\langle1,1\rangle$,$\langle -1,1\rangle$,$\langle1,0\rangle$, $\langle -1,0\rangle$. How do I formally word this? The next part asks me to find the group $\operatorname{Aut}( \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_{2})$, I think it could be related.

Comment: Your notation is bad. Elements of the group have the form $(x,y)$, not $\langle x,y \rangle$, and you mean $\langle x \rangle \times \langle (0,1) \rangle$. Since $1$ and $-1$ are the only generators of ${\mathbb Z}$, the four elements you describe are the only possible candidates for $x$. So you just need to check that all of them really do satisfy the required equality. And yes, it is relevant to the calculation of the automorphism group, since these values of $x$ are the only possible images of $(1,0)$ under an automorphism.